# Align table justify and add img to docx

Tags: python

i generate a report and save it as a doc file, im having some troubles in the design part.

Its better to show you. You can see bellow what i have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x4g1.png)

Here is what i need
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eD0z.png)

Can someone help?

Here is my code

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.shared import Pt, Cm
from docx2pdf import convert
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
import docx

best_drivers_pdf=['dd-33-44:::12:::A','dd-23-44:::10:::A','dd-33-45:::6:::D','dd-33-44:::9:::B']

docpath = "Reports/file.docx"
mydoc = docx.Document()

section_g = mydoc.sections
section_h = mydoc.sections[0]
header = section_h.header
header_para = header.paragraphs[0]
footer = section_h.footer
footer_para = footer.paragraphs[0]

mydoc.sections[0].header_distance = Cm(0)
mydoc.sections[0].footer_distance = Cm(0)

runhead = header_para.add_run()
runhead.add_picture(path_logo.strip(), width=docx.shared.Cm(21.7), height=docx.shared.Cm(4.2))

runfoot = footer_para.add_run()
runfoot.add_picture("client_report/report_img/bottom.png", width=docx.shared.Cm(21.7),height=docx.shared.Cm(2.5))

for section in section_g:
    section.top_margin = Cm(0)
    section.bottom_margin = Cm(0)
    section.left_margin = Cm(0)
    section.right_margin = Cm(0)



styles = mydoc.styles
style = styles.add_style('Tahoma', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
style.font.name = 'Tahoma'
style.font.size = Pt(11)

shd = OxmlElement('w:background')
shd.set(qn('w:color'), '407294')
mydoc.element.insert(0, shd)
shd1 = OxmlElement('w:displayBackgroundShape')
mydoc.settings.element.insert(0, shd1)





mydoc.add_heading('Best Drivers', 1).alignment = 1
tablebest = mydoc.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
tablebest.style = 'Colorful List'
row = tablebest.rows[0].cells
row[0].text = ''
row[1].text = 'vehicle'
row[2].text = 'Points'
row[3].text = 'Grade'
for x in best_drivers_pdf:
    p, v, g = x.split(":::")
    row = tablebest.add_row().cells
    row[0].text = ''
    #row[0].add_picture("report_img/green_car.png", width=docx.shared.Cm(2),height=docx.shared.Cm(2))
    row[1].text = str(v)
    row[2].text = str(p)
    row[3].text = str(g)
tablebest.alignment = WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.CENTER

mydoc.save(docpath)
```

Can someone help me get the table justify to center and add img to the first row of each table? First row is left empty for that porpuse but i cant seem to do it :(

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: @itprorh66, Done, changed the code

Answer (score 0):

```
                for x in range(0, 5):
                    for cell in tablebest.columns[x].cells:
                        if x==0 or x==4:
                            cell.width = Cm(3)
                        else:
                            cell.width = Cm(2)
                        cell.paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
```